# How do submit dynamically generated form fields to processing page with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, forms

I am working on a somewhat lengthy form that has a section where a block of form fields are dynamically added/removed. So far I have not been able to find a way to make this method work.

For example, if I add 3 subcontractors and fill in the input for each, the ngmodel holds the value as it should. However, if I remove one of the fields the ngmodel is still holding the input value. Additionally, if I remove the 2nd field in the series it doesn't actually remove that instance, it just reduces the count so instead of having field #1 and field #3 like I should, I actually have field #1 and field #2.

The end result in all of this is to submit to the process page and have a loop iterate through the total # of added fields and insert them into a db.

I'm new to angularjs so I'm not sure that the method I am attempting is even best practice as it seems to be overly complex, so I am open to suggestions on how to improve the process as well.

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-repeat="subcontractor in subcontractors">
   <div class="well well-sm">Subcontractor #{{subcontractor.id}}<span id="subCounter"></span>
     <button type="button" ng-click="removeSub()" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <label for="subName">Subcontractor Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subName" name="subName" placeholder="Subcontractor" ng-model="formData.subName['subName'+($index+1)]">
     </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" ng-show="showAddSub(subcontractor)" ng-click="addNewSub()">[+] Add New Sub</button>
 </div>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
$scope.addNewSub = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.subcontractors.length+1;
  $scope.subcontractors.push({'id': +newItemNo});
};

$scope.removeSub = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.subcontractors.length-1;
  $scope.subcontractors.splice($scope.subcontractors-1, 1);
};

$scope.showAddSub = function(subcontractor) {
  return subcontractor.id === $scope.subcontractors[$scope.subcontractors.length-1].id;
};
```

Comment: How does your `removeSub` method know which `subcontractor` the user wants to remove?

Comment: Currently there is not a way for it to know specifically which to remove which is part of the problem. I am able to remove based on the index position. I would like to be able to identify specific iterations of the form addition to remove. I've read in other posts about using `ngForm` to control each iteration individually but the post was from an older version of angularjs and I'm not sure if that's still best practice.

Comment: I don't think `ngForm` is relevant to your specific iterations problem. `ngForm` is simply a form that can be nested for validation purposes. Regular html forms cannot be nested. Can you create a plunker with an example of your code?  That way it will be easy for me to help you.

Comment: I've never used plunker before and for some reason I'm not able to get the angularjs to work correctly on there but here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/lq0hqABDcH9LoPPpITjn

Also, only the first form field is actually coded for iteration, I wanted to get one working before changing the rest.

Comment: It works here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/JhOQBAycKPlQl1ypJZBe?p=preview  I just deleted the dependencies of your app for this example.

Comment: Also, I added `$scope.formData.subName = {};` to your controller so the name wouldn't return any console errors. Be sure to open up the console when using plunkr to see any errors.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense about the dependencies needing to be out.

Comment: Here's a link to a version that is working with the add button: http://plnkr.co/edit/3azfxzIRlD2D7tJZh0QQ

Comment: The add button doesn't work for me.

Comment: You may have to save your work.  I don't see any `submitting` method for that link.

Comment: Try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/tCVFugSbFoVJgUydDJzY
For some reason you have to do the popout preview for it to work correctly.